# How to pivot on 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
date       |  shop | rank_1 | rank2
-----------+-------+--------+------
01.01.2020 |   ZZZ |      1 |     3
01.01.2020 |   YYY |      2 |     4
01.01.2020 |   DDD |      3 |     5
01.01.2020 |   UUU |      4 |     1
01.01.2020 | LLLLL |      5 |     2
```

Table looks like this and I want to transform, so that it looked like this:

```
date       | rank_1_1 | rank_1_2 | rank_1_3 | rank_1_4 | rank_1_5 | ...
-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------
01.01.2020 |      ZZZ |      YYY |      DDD |      UUU |    LLLLL | ...
```

Comment: If you mean SQL, Oracle has a "pivot()" operation: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: You can not create a dynamic number of columns. is number of columns required in expected output is defined or variable? (What do you mean by `...` in other columns?)

Comment: by .. I mean that there will be rank_2 1 rank_2 2 and their values and yes number of columns are fixed, I mean there must be 5 columns for each rank division

Comment: and there will be always 5 values for the given date or it is variable number?

Comment: Check the oracle pivot function. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck ?

Comment: @Koen Lostrie tried to use pivot but got stuck, can take shop name by rank_1 for example =1 and have to write 'ZZZ' the problem with second rank_2, I am doing loop with rank_1, code below:
select * from 
(select t.date,t.shop_name, t.rank_1 from temp t)
pivot (max(shop_name)
for rank_1 in (
1 as TOP_1_BY_SUM,
2 as TOP_2_BY_SUM,
3 as TOP_3_BY_SUM,
4 as TOP_4_BY_SUM,
5 as TOP_5_BY_SUM
)
);
I want continuation with rank_2 is it possible, any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot allows you to display column data in a row. You want to convert *2 columns* into rows which is a bit trickier. I added a comment for each subquery to explain what I did. Best way to understand it is tear it apart again and check what happens.

```
WITH /* sample data */
mydata (thedate, shop, rank_1, rank_2) AS
(
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-01', 'ZZZ', 1, 3 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-01', 'YYY', 2, 4 FROM DUAL
  UNION  
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-01', 'DDD', 3, 5 FROM DUAL
  UNION  
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-01', 'UUU', 4, 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION  
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-01', 'LLLLL', 5, 2 FROM DUAL
  UNION  
  SELECT DATE'2020-01-02', 'AAA', 5, 2 FROM DUAL
), 
/* extract only first column */
my_data_rank1 (thedate, shop, rank_1)
AS
(
SELECT thedate,
       shop,
       rank_1
  FROM mydata
),
/* extract only 2nd column */
my_data_rank2 (thedate, shop, rank_2)
AS
(
SELECT thedate,
       shop,
       rank_2
  FROM mydata
),
/* pivot on 1st column */
rank1_pivot_data AS
(
SELECT * FROM my_data_rank1  
PIVOT (MAX(shop) for rank_1 IN ('1' rank_1_1, '2' rank_1_2, '3' rank_1_3 , '4' rank_1_4 , '5' rank_1_5 ))
),
/* pivot on 2nd column */
 rank2_pivot_data AS
(
SELECT * FROM my_data_rank2  
PIVOT (MAX(shop) for rank_2 IN ('1' rank_2_1, '2' rank_2_2, '3' rank_2_3 , '4' rank_2_4 , '5' rank_2_5 ))
),
/* combine both rows. this will give you 2 rows: one for rank_1 and one for rank_2 */
combined_data (thedate, rank_1_1,rank_1_2,rank_1_3,rank_1_4,rank_1_5,rank_2_1,rank_2_2,rank_2_3,rank_2_4,rank_2_5) AS
(
 SELECT thedate, rank_1_1,rank_1_2,rank_1_3,rank_1_4,rank_1_5,null,null,null,null,null
   FROM rank1_pivot_data
 UNION ALL
 SELECT thedate, null,null,null,null,null,rank_2_1,rank_2_2,rank_2_3,rank_2_4,rank_2_5
   FROM rank2_pivot_data
),
/* merge the rows into 1 */
combined_data_merged  (thedate, rank_1_1,rank_1_2,rank_1_3,rank_1_4,rank_1_5,rank_2_1,rank_2_2,rank_2_3,rank_2_4,rank_2_5) 
AS 
(
 SELECT thedate, MAX(rank_1_1),MAX(rank_1_2),MAX(rank_1_3),MAX(rank_1_4),MAX(rank_1_5),MAX(rank_2_1),MAX(rank_2_2),MAX(rank_2_3),MAX(rank_2_4),MAX(rank_2_5)
   FROM combined_data
   GROUP BY thedate
)
SELECT * FROM combined_data_merged;


THEDATE     RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_ RANK_
----------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
01-JAN-2020 ZZZ   YYY   DDD   UUU   LLLLL UUU   LLLLL ZZZ   YYY   DDD  
02-JAN-2020                         AAA         AAA
```

Comment: "You want to convert 2 columns into rows which is a bit trickier."
Got you, thanks a lot